# Why does Prince T'Challa have a 6-sided TV in "Black Panther"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, realism, black-panther

Early in *Black Panther*, Prince T'Challa is shown in a control room, watching the regular news on a TV that has 6 sides instead of being rectangular.  This is a mock-up of what I mean:

[image]

Is there any logic in the movie that makes a 6-sided TV screen make sense? Or is this just the [rule of cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool)?

Comment: It’s widely known that [hexagons are inherently high-tech](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HighTechHexagons).

Answer (score 2):

Considering the level of tech that Wakanda possesses in the film, it's reasonable to assume that they invented the television screen well before the rest of the world.

For whatever reason, they opted for a hexagonal shape rather than rectangular. The only reason we're used to one over the other is that all our screens are like that.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure it wasn't a Wakandan broadcast. It was from another country, English-speaking, and presumably broadcast as a rectangle. Warping the image to fit a hexagon would make it all distorted.

Comment: @BrettFromLA: According to the answer, the **TV screen** was Wakandan-made, not the TV show. (also, somewhat facetiously, warping an image would indeed make things distorted, since those are [synonyms  (see 1.1)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/warp))

Comment: @Flater Copy that about warping = distorted! :-) My point was that either the Wakanda hexateevee would cut off the corners of the rectangular image, which would omit crucial information, or the rectangular image should be "letterboxed" (or something similar) within the hexateevee, with black areas around the rectangular image. If the rectangular image was curved to fit in the hexateevee then much of the image and text would be hard to view (because of all the warpy distortion).

Comment: @BrettFromLA it's worth noting that even our own TVs can chop off vital information when switching a standard resolution to widescreen (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

The television have 6 sides because the movie wanted to present the viewer with the technological development of the Wakanada, but in a different style.

Comment: Can you point out a little more what the 6-sided screen has to do with the technological development of Wakanda or in which way it represents African culture?